# Knockout template using data-bind to image src property not working

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, knockout-templating

I cannot see what is wrong here but the image does not display using the following Knockout template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="legend-template">       
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-bind="click : doSomething" ></input>
        <img width="16px" height="16px" data-bind="src: 'imagePath'" />          
        <span data-bind="text : label"> </span>
    </div>        
</script>
```

The object this is being bound to looks like this:

```
tut.myObject= function (imagePath, label) {
    this.label = ko.observable(label);
    this.imagePath = ko.observable(imagePath || liveString + '/Content/images/marker.png');   
};

tut.myObject.prototype = {
    doSomething: function () { alert("do what?");
     }
};
```

When the HTML object is rendered I see the label and clicking on the checkbox invokes doSomething.

TIA.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Only a few attributes can be bound directly; try using `attr` - it will let you set any attribute on an element.

```
<img width="16px" height="16px" data-bind="attr:{src: imagePath}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for response BUT when this gives me the following error:  Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: SyntaxError: Expected ':';
Bindings value: attr {src: imagePath}

Comment: Got it, thanks.  Should be <img width="16px" height="16px" data-bind="attr : {src: imagePath}" />

Comment: sorry about that - #note to self: don't answer questions watching "Die Hard 3" again ;)

Comment: fyi: image tag width and height attributes shouldnt have "px"
<img width="16" height="16" data-bind="attr:{src: imagePath}" />

Comment: This is quite an old answer - BEWARE - the framework may have changed

Comment: I am using the latest version 3.4.0 and this answer still works just fine.