# Binding image source from a directory in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

```
<ul style="list-style:none;" data-bind="foreach: Images">
    <li style="display:inline;">
        <a class="inline" data-bind="attr: { href: $data }"><img data-bind="attr:{ src:  $data }" width="150" height="150" style="padding:5px;" /></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Why the code above isn't working at all? I mean it's not displaying any images from the path given.

```
$data = "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\meal_service\\images\\img7.jpg"
```

do you know what was happening here? Thanks.

Comment: it should work check here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/26845/

Comment: This type of problem is easiest to debug yourself. Get to know your developer toolbar. Inspect the img rendered by Knockout, check the actual `src` attribute it got, and check the "network" tab of your dev tools to see the request go out / not go out. More then likely your answer is there.

Answer (score 1):

You should not bind the `Directory path` to the image source in web page. Since, if you give the Directory path directly to the image `src` it will refer the local system path. It won't load the image from server. Its wrong approach.

The [Q and A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659665/knockout-template-using-data-bind-to-image-src-property-not-working) available.

***For Example:***

```
Images.push('../Download/Images/' + image.name);
```

If you use chrome you can right click on the image and Try to `open image in New Tab` and check the image url / edit and try the correct path.

Something Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTJDc.jpg?s=328&g=1).,

You have to load the image src as `your domain path with image path`.