# Add image icon only to parent <li > and not the child <li>

Tags: javascript, html, image, knockout.js, html-lists

I have an HTML page which shows the data in in list form. It uses Tree hierarchy to load the data which comes up in the form of

```
<ul>
  <li>A
    <ul>
      <li>subsection</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>B
    <ul>
      <li>subsection</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

I'm using this to fetch the data from json file.

```
<li data-bind="attr: {id: $data['id']"> <div class="container"> <strong><span data-bind="text: $data['name']" class="oj-navigationlist-item-title speech"></span></strong></div></li>
```

Now I want to add a image icon only to the parent and not to the child dynamically.

Comment: What framework you're using?

Comment: How are you adding the icon?

Comment: so what's not working? What does the image have to do with the code you've shown?

Comment: I'm using Knockout.js.  I just have to add small image icon on parent <LI>

Comment: How to add the image icon on parent <LI>  only

Comment: @user3780690 should probably include fact you're using `Knockout.js` in question, and how you're using it to create the list. Seems significant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659665/knockout-template-using-data-bind-to-image-src-property-not-working may help

Comment: I;m looking for something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830624/target-first-level-lis-and-not-the-nested-lis

Comment: The only difference is that my parent and child <li> are coming dynamically. Hence I dont understand how to restrict image icon to only appear on parent <li>